# SwiftUI scaleEffect and layout bounds

Tags: swiftui

I want to create a `Text` view with slighter larger than normal font.  I tried,

```
Text("Foo").scaleEffect(1.3)
```

The text is larger as desired, but the layout uses the original borders, so the "Foo" is going off the bottom of the screen. Is there a way make it use the new larger bounds for layout?

I know there are named fonts, so I could do:

```
Text("Foo").font(.title)
```

but I wanted to say "1.3 times bigger than `.body`".

Answer (score 1):

Here is possible approach

```
Text("Hello")
    .font(Font.system(size: UIFont.systemFontSize * 1.3))
```